# Using VBA macro to insert functions VS only using macro

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

In short, I would either:

Create a macro that runs every time a cell within a certain range is changed, and then writing out the result based on those cells.
-OR-
Create a macro to automatically insert functions that would do the same thing

Things to consider are that this would need to work on multiple tables of varying length without need to manually change anything, and that the results of individual sheets would need to be also displayed in summary on another page.

Which would be more desirable/more efficient/easier to implement?

The subject data entails testing procedures. Sheets contain testing criteria and a column containing PASS/FAIL results. I need to tabulate these. The start of the table and the end of the table are at different rows and are subject to changing.

Comment: can you please provide some sample data so that readers can better understand your issue and therefore devise the best solution?

Comment: Have you considered using array formulas? Consider also the end user.  If he is going to use the formula or add it in new position, a function might be the best.  If not, a macro gives you more power and control.  But again, it depends on what exactly do you need.  As Remnant said; put some examples to give a more suited opinion.

Comment: @CaBieberach - If I were to do it through formulas, I'd most likely use countif(). The problem that is making me consider macros are that: I could import the macro into the workbook, whereas equations would need to be added to each sheet manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing your actual problem I would definitely go for the first option. Having many formulas inserted into cells dynamically I think would be a pain.

Use the Worksheet_Change event and test whether the cell changed is one of your target range, then perform whichever action is required.

Comment: I would need the results to be written at the bottom of the table, which may change in length. That's the only reason I'm considering functions, because they stay in their proper cell after you insert rows above them.How much effort would it take to make sure that the results are inserted in the same position relative to the end of the table?

Comment: How is the table generated? And how is the row/column insertion to the table happening? If you have control of both of these things then just set up a variable to keep track of the table size. If this is not possible then you will need to detect the end of the table using something like .end(xlDown) etc. See http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/ExcelRanges.htm